# MySQL MY-011092 Upgrading the data dictionary from dictionary version '0' is not supported

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am installing the MySql:latest container image. But get a data dictionary error. What does it mean?

```
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.1.0-1.2.13-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.1.0-1.2.13-server
[System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
[Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.1.0) starting as process 1
[System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
[System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
[ERROR] [MY-011092] [Server] Upgrading the data dictionary from dictionary version '0' is not supported.
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.1.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
```